# Shopify orders/create webhook doesn't work

Tags: shopify, webhooks, shopify-app, shopify-api

I'm trying to build a shopify app which users(customers) get automatically notified with e-mail, to achive this I'm trying to use orders/create webhook and test it by buying an item for free in the development store that my app is installed. But it doesn't work without giving an error in the console.

Here's my related code in the main index.js file;

```
import nodemailer from "nodemailer";

const smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: "gmail",
  auth: {
    user: "*****@gmail.com",
    pass: "*******"
  }
});

async function sendEmail(to, subject, html) {
  const mailOptions = {
    from: "*****@gmail.com",
    to,
    subject,
    html
  };

  return smtpTransport.sendMail(mailOptions, (err, data)=>{
    if(err) console.log(err)
    else console.log("mail sent.")
  });
}
```

```
import { Shopify } from "@shopify/shopify-api";


Shopify.Webhooks.Registry.addHandler("ORDERS_CREATE", {
  path: "/api/webhooks",
  webhookHandler: async (_topic, _shop, body) => {
    // Parse the request body
    const payload = JSON.parse(body);

    // Get the email and name of the customer who made the purchase
    const { email, customer: { first_name, last_name } } = payload.customer;

    // Get the shipping address of the order
    const {
      address1,
      address2,
      city,
      province,
      country,
      zip
    } = payload.shipping_address;

    // Compose the email message
    const html = `
      <p>Dear ${first_name} ${last_name},</p>
      <p>Thank you for your purchase! Your order will be shipped to the following address:</p>
      <p>
        ${address1}<br>
        ${address2 ? address2 + "<br>" : ""}
        ${city}, ${province} ${zip}<br>
        ${country}
      </p>
      <p>We hope you enjoy your purchase!</p>
    `;

    // Send the email
    await sendEmail(
      email,
      "Thank you for your purchase!",
      html
    );
  },
});
```

```
 app.post("/api/webhooks", async (req, res) => {
    try {
      await Shopify.Webhooks.Registry.process(req, res);
      console.log(`Webhook processed, returned status code 200`);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(`Failed to process webhook: ${e.message}`);
      if (!res.headersSent) {
        res.status(500).send(e.message);
      }
    }
  });
```

Comment: You need to clarify what you mean when you say it does work. Your question has a million options for answers, so you narrowing down your real problem would be helpful.

Comment: I tried to say that the webhook doesn't execute and I don't know why, I wish I can narrow down the problem since it doesn't show any error I can't determine what is missing. But my guess is, the code I provided here isn't the problem. There must be steps that I'm missing. Is there any other additional step for registering a webhook? Or `Shopify.Webhooks.Registry.addHandler` is enough? 
I can't find any example of registering a webhook. Thank you very much for your response and I'm sorry for my inexperience in the field.

Comment: When you make a request to add a webhook, Shopify sends you back a response. Examine the response you get, as it contains the ID of webhook if it was created, letting you know it was created, or the error if you failed to send a correct request. That is how you debug this issue.